# How to change the temperature unit of Google's weather notification?

Tags: google-now, localization, weather

I have my Google Now weather set to Celsius, but when it showed on the notification bar, it's still Fahrenheit.

[image]

How to change this?

If it matters, the device is Motorola X Style with Android 7

Comment: Tried this and was able to get Celsius after a while on a Nexus 7 running Android 5.1. If possible, OP should update question with device/OS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but after some phone restart the notification bar is showed in Celsius now. So I post this to close question.